# Job ids retrieval from ID. Big set of jobs

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I'm in the need of running a lot of jobs in the IBM backends. If one likes to run in parallel two jobs (say, with two different parameters), I have seen in the `Jobs` webpage that sometimes the jobs are mixed. What I mean with this is that e.g. in the downloadable cvs file, row 3 belongs to job 1 and row 4 to job 2. To filter out every single cell in the cvs does not appear feasible.

Now, in qiskit, if I send a big job, this is partitioned into several chunks, something that `job_set_foo.report(detailed=True)` returns is:

```
Job set name: 2021-07-22T14:09:01.003237
      ID: XXXX-YYYY
    tags: []
...
Detail report:
  experiments: 0-74
    job index: 0
    job ID: ZZZ1
...
```

So suppose that my ID `XXX-YYY` contains 20 jobs ids `ZZZx`. Is there a way to, from directly the ID, retrieve as a list all the `ZZZx`'s jobs ids?

*`job_set_foo = job_manager.run(circuits, backend=backend, shots=2**13)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all what you want is a list of all job IDs for the jobs in a job set:

```
job_set = job_manager.retrieve_job_set(job_set_id = 'XXX-YYY', provider = provider)
id_list = [ job.job_id() for job in job_set.jobs() ]
```

Comment: I had 14 jobs but the method you describe only gives me a list with 10 ids. Any idea what was going on?

Comment: The code works for me with more than 14 jobs!
Are you sure you are passing the right job set ID?

Comment: Ah, that's weird. I ran another set of jobs and it appears now complete. Thanks for the snippet!